# Download django chat app

Tags: django, django-models, download, django-templates, django-views

Hot to download this django chat app  http://code.google.com/p/django-jqchat/ are there any alternatives the svn link seems to be broken

Comment: Don't know but the `svn checkout http://django-jqchat.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ django-jqchat-read-only` works for me.

Comment: I get an error saying could not resolve django-jqchat.googlecode.com(Host not found) and i am not able to ping it

Comment: can any one upload a tar of it if u are able to download it

Comment: http://dev.grovemade.com/site_media/jqchat-foar-you.tgz

Answer (score 0):

```
svn checkout http://django-jqchat.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ django-jqchat
```

worked fine for me

Comment: I get an error saying could not resolve django-jqchat.googlecode.com(Host not found)   and i am not able to ping it